# RxJava Zip not working properly

Tags: kotlin, zip, retrofit2, rx-java2, flatmap

I am trying to implement this complex API structure. [image: API Structure]

So I tried to implement it with RxJava2 `zip` for parallel requests

```
  private fun getDetails(marketDataQuotes: MarketDataQuotes, instrumentById: InstrumentById, subscribe: Subscribe): Observable<DetailsWatchListModel> {
    return Observable.zip(
            getMarketDataQutoes(marketDataQuotes),
            getInstrumentById(instrumentById),
            getSubscribeInstrument(subscribe),
            Function3<MarketDataQuotesResponse, List<InstrumentByIdResponse>, SubscribeResult,DetailsWatchListModel>
            { marketData, instrumentList, subscribeInstrument ->
                detailWatchList(marketData, instrumentList, subscribeInstrument)
            })

}
```

but facing this Issue [image: Error]

```
private fun getSubscribeInstrument(subscribe: Subscribe): LiveData<SubscribeResult> {
    val mutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<SubscribeResult>()
    remoteServices.requestSubscribe(subscribe)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            //  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(object : ErrorCallBack<BaseResponse<SubscribeResult>>() {
                override fun onSuccess(t: BaseResponse<SubscribeResult>) {
                    L.d("Success of Market data Quotes")
                    // mutableLiveData.value = transform(t)
                }

            })
    return mutableLiveData
}
```

And other API calls are like this with single place error handling and base Response Structre

And Service like

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("instruments/subscription")
fun requestSubscribe(@Body subscribe: Subscribe): Observable<BaseResponse<SubscribeResult>>
```

Using Kotlin v1.2.21 , retofit 2.3.0 , RxJava2 2.1.5 Please let me know what i am doing wrong.. Tanx in Advance

Comment: I'm no Kotlin programmer, but try `object : Function3` (etc.) with `zip`.

Comment: can u provide me a sample code. i try that also but still facing issue

Answer (score 0):

`LiveData` cannot be zipped with RxJava.

You need to use this API: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveDataReactiveStreams.html

So convert your LiveData to RxJava  and then zip it.